# How start calculate statistics about internal Lua performance?

Tags: lua, lua-table

How to determine Lua internal performance, i.e. start calculate statistics on table count, reference count, function call count and other.

I guess that my Lua scenario internal performance issue in manipulate with table (i.e.  create a lot of table >= 1200) and this is performance problem to my scenario.

I would like to avoid redesigning scenario and ensure point of bottleneck.

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ProfilingLuaCode

Comment: Hmmm. I expect some C API callback with status or C API global hook.

Comment: What you expect doesn't matter.  If it's not there, it's not there.  That said, you can compile the Lua interpreter with profiling instrumentation, but that will profile the interpreter itself rather than your code. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [debug library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.10), that should help you quite a bit already.

Using [`os.clock()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.clock) to time execution times of blocks of code can also help you identify roughly where your bottlenecks are.

Lookin at the instructions generated from your program using `luac -p -l` can also give you lots of insight into how things work and what might be causing your code to run slow.

---

Here's a short example of how you can even output the instructions of a function at runtime:

```
local function map(f, a, ...) -- Just a simple example function :)
  if a then
    return f(a), map(f, ...)
  end
end

-- This is where the magic happens ;)
f = io.popen('luac -l -p -', 'w')
f:write(string.dump(map))
f:close()
```